# Find the largest region over which the function f is increasing or decreasing, for $ f(x) = 18x-6\sin(6x) $

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Let $ f(x) = 18x-6\sin(6x) $ for  $\displaystyle 0 \le x \le \frac{\pi }{3} $

Find the largest region over which the function f is increasing or decreasing.

$f$ is increasing for $x \in$ ?

$f$ is decreasing for $x \in$ ?

I found some parts of the answers. See below.

I find the critical numbers by taking the derivative of the original function and setting it equal to zero.

$ 18 - 36\cos(6x) = 0 $ - > $ \cos(6x) = \frac {1}{2}$ -> $ 6x = \frac {\pi}{3} $

$ x = \frac {\pi}{18} $

So the intervals are: $[0, \frac {\pi}{18}), (\frac {\pi}{18}, \frac {\pi}{3}]$

Since f is continuous throughout, the critical number $\frac {\pi}{18}$ is included

On the interval $[\frac {\pi}{18}, \frac {\pi}{3}],$  f'(x) > $0$

On the interval $[0, \frac {\pi}{18}],$ f'(x) < $0$

But for some reason, where function is increasing, the right endpoint is incorrect. Why?

And when the function is decreasing there's another interval that I'm missing, what is it?

Comment: You have forgotten that $\cos 6x= 0$ has several solutions.

Comment: Do you mean 6x = $\frac{-\pi }{3} $ (or x = $\frac{-\pi }{18} $)?? It cannot be, since I'm limited to between 0 and $\frac{\pi }{3} $ I can't have a negative critical number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

$$\cos(6x) = \dfrac{1}{2} \implies 6x = \color{blue}{\pm} \frac{\pi}{3} + 2n\pi, ~n\in \mathbb{Z}$$

Comment: How can I have  6x = $\frac{-\pi }{3}$ if the function is given for $\displaystyle 0 \le x \le \frac{\pi }{3} $

Comment: Good observation :) Make $n$ positive to get a positive value for $x$ $$6x = \color{blue}{\pm} \frac{\pi}{3} + 2n\pi \implies x =   \color{blue}{\pm} \frac{\pi}{18} + \frac{n\pi}{3} $$

Comment: Notice that both $\frac{\pi}{18} + \frac{0\pi}{3} = \frac{\pi}{18}$ and  $\color{blue}{-}\frac{\pi}{18} + \frac{1\pi}{3} = \frac{5\pi}{18}$ fall under the given bounds.